# Citing with "Cf." in natbib in the footnote

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using footnotes within the text and want to cite in the footnote as follows:

Cf. Parker (2012), p. 200

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt} %scrreprt
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

An example how I am citing currently.\footnote{\cite{Parker}, p. 200}


\end{document}
```

I am using the natbib citation style. Glad to receive any suggestion on how to include the "Cf." in the footnote.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for adding a minimal example. For future bibliography related questions it would also be useful to include the `\bibliographystyle` line and the `\bibliography` command in the example, although for your particular question these are not really crucial.

Answer (score 2):

The `natbib` citation commands support a post-note for `\citet` (i.e., Author (year) citations), and both a pre-note and post-note for `\citep` (i.e., (Author, Year) citations). So in your case you can't really achieve the look you want automatically. Normally in author/year citations, the page references show up inside the parentheses.  So here are your options:

Use `\citep[cf.][p. 200]{Parker}` to get:

> (cf. Parker, 2012, p. 200)

Use `cf. \citet[p. 200]{Parker}` to get:

> cf. Parker (2012, p. 200)

Or do everything manually by useing `cf. \citet{Parker}, p. 200` to get what you seem to  want:

> cf. Parker (2012), p. 200